# Why php.ini error_reporting ignored by IIS?

Tags: php, iis, settings, reporting

IIS 8.5 on 2012R2 with php 5.6

Editing the correct `php.ini` file, web site is using `php-cgi.exe` in same folder of `php.ini`, all other settings are correctly applied (logfilepath, plugin , etc, ...)

However, `error_reporting` directive is ignored, I've set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`, but in the log file I have a tons of:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  
PHP Deprecated:
```

Comment: Check that you set display_errors = On in your php.ini file. also, check you give enough permission to access the php.ini file.try to give iusr or iis_usrs permission to php.ini file. [link](https://serverfault.com/a/19566)

Comment: set display_errors i set to ON , php.ini file have everyone full control permissions

Comment: Try to set configuration editor->system.webServer->httpErrors change errorMode to Detailed from DetailedLocalOnly.